# Connect to a SOAP API with savon and specify Domain

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

With SoapUI, I am successfully connecting to a SOAP API with details such as:

```
Initial WSDL: http://11.11.1.11:7303/FOO/BAR/BAZ
Username: foo
Password: bar
Domain: example
```

But I am not sure how to do this with [Savon](http://savonrb.com). I am trying this (not quite understanding if [ntlm](http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html) is the correct setting here):

```rb
savon_defaults   =  {
  :wsdl                     => "http://11.11.1.11:7303/FOO/BAR/BAZ",
  :ntlm                     => ["foo", "bar", "example"],
  :log_level                => :debug,
  :pretty_print_xml         => true,
  :log                      => true
}
@client = Savon.client(savon_defaults)
@client.call(:foo, :message => {:bar => "baz"})
```

The above outputs:

```
D, [2020-05-18T21:21:14.853929 #7156] DEBUG -- : HTTPI /peer GET request to 11.11.1.11 (httpclient)
Savon::HTTPError: HTTP error (401)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try change the `:ntlm` to `:wsse_auth`? If it doesn't success either, try change the `"example"` to `:digest`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Seems I am getting the same output as before, in both cases.